# Copy data of ArrayList into a array

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have an `Array` and an `ArrayList` like below

```
String[] stringArray = new String[] {"a","b","c","d","e"};

List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<>();
stringList.add("p");
stringList.add("q");
stringList.add("r");
```

I want to copy stringList to stringArray. I tried with `ArrayList.toArray()` method but it set **null** to **fourth** element of `Array`. Is there any way I can do this by without using a **for loop**

Expected O/P

```
{"p","q","r","d","e"}
```

Comment: What would you like to have as a result?

Comment: what should happen if stringList contains more values than stringArray?

Comment: @Original Then complete array should be created by the list

Comment: ok checkout my updated answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to just overwrite existing elements in the `stringArray`, without touching those at farther indexes, use [`System#arraycopy(Object, int, Object, int, int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29):

```
// Convert list to array
String[] stringListAsArray = stringList.toArray(new String[] {});

// Copy
System.arraycopy(stringListAsArray, 0, 
                 stringArray, 0, stringListAsArray.length);
```

Also, make sure the `stringList` is not longer than `stringArray` or you'll get [`IndexOutOfBoundsExceptions`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IndexOutOfBoundsException.html).

Answer (score 2):

Array has static memory declaration thus you cannot increase the number cells.

to do this, you can convert the stringArray to list using `Arrays.asList(stringArray);`
then add the two lists and finally convert it back to an array.

Answer (score 1):

`ArrayList.toArray` behaves as you saw (setting the element following the end of the List to null) :

```
 * <p>If the list fits in the specified array with room to spare
 * (i.e., the array has more elements than the list), the element in
 * the array immediately following the end of the collection is set to
 * <tt>null</tt>.  (This is useful in determining the length of the
 * list <i>only</i> if the caller knows that the list does not contain
 * any null elements.)
```

You could convert the List to a new array and then copy that array to the start of the original array.

```
String arr2 = stringList.toArray(new String[stringList.size()]);
System.arraycopy (arr2, 0, stringArray, 0, arr2.length);
```

Answer (score 1):

If your stringList contains less or equal number of Strings like your stringArray you can do it like this:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < stringList.size(); i++) {
        stringArray[i] = stringList.get(i);
    }
```

**Update**
This way will either update the existing array or use the generated array from the list if it contains more values

```
    String[] listAsArray = stringList.toArray(new String[stringList.size()]);
    if (listAsArray.length <= stringArray.length) {
        for (int i = 0; i < listAsArray.length; i++) {
            stringArray[i] = listAsArray[i];
        }
    } else {
        stringArray = listAsArray;
    }
```